Three congruences for a Perrin-like sequence and pseudoprimes
Let $ V(n) $ be defined by the recurrence relation:
$$
V(n) = 3\,V(n-2) + V(n-3)
$$
with the initial conditions:
$$
V(0) = 3, \quad V(1) = 0, \quad \text{and} \quad V(2) = 6.
$$
If $ n $ is an odd prime and satisfies:
$$
n \equiv \pm2 \quad \text{or} \quad n \equiv \pm4 \pmod{9},
$$
then the following congruences hold:
1.
$$
   V(n) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}
   $$
2.
$$
   V(n+1) \equiv -3 \pmod{n}
   $$
3.
$$
   V(n+2) \equiv 3 \quad \text{or} \quad V(n+2) \equiv -6 \pmod{n}
   $$
For the derivation and explanation of the third congruence, please refer to this recent Mathematics Stack Exchange thread.
Do there exist odd composite numbers $ n $ with $ n \equiv \pm2 $ or $ n \equiv \pm4 \pmod{9} $ that satisfy all three congruences (1), (2), and (3)?
This is analogous to the Perrin pseudoprime question; Adams and Shanks found a composite $n$ such that $n$ divides $P(n)$ where $P$ is the Perrin sequence (ref.: Wikipedia entry on Perrin number).
Note: It seems likely that for $n\gt3$ prime, the congruence condition modulo 9 is equivalent to requiring that $x^3-3x-1$ be irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{n}$. With respect to irreducibility, please refer to Jyrki Lahtonen's comments mentioning class field theory in this Mathematics Stack Exchange thread:.

In the language of Adams and Shanks, there are three possible situations for primes (and thus three possible types of pseudoprimes), denoted Q, S and I.
For the S-primes, the polynomial factors completely. In this case, I was able to prove that there are infinitely many S-pseudoprimes.
For the Q-primes, the polynomial factors into a linear and quadratic. In this case, Pomerance has a heuristic that applies and convincingly argues that there are infinitely many Q-pseudoprimes. Nobody, however, knows how to compute one during the life of this universe.
For the I-primes, the polynomial is irreducible. This seems to be the case you're interested in. I'm unaware of any heuristics in this case as to the existence of I-pseudoprimes.

Thanks for your reply. From looking at the Adams and Shanks paper, the criterion for $p$ being an I-prime seems to be expressibility by a quadratic form. The authors only consider polynomials $f$ yielding non-abelian extension fields. I'm puzzled as to whether there's a reason not to look at $f$ yielding abelian extensions, for which I'm told class field theory appplies.
